# Getting the Prompt for Next Command in Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Whenever I type the name of an application to open it, the application opens, but after opening it, the terminal seems to be busy with a process so that it doesn't give me the prompt for the next command (I mean following the $ sign). Then I can't type any more command in the terminal and I have to exit it pressing the close button (at the top left) which in turn kills the process. Please note that I am using precise pangolin & this problem seems to be pertaining to all the processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a `&` after the name of the app, e.g.:

```
firefox &
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But what's the significance of the ampersand? What exactly the terminal expects after opening the application unless I enter &?

Comment: Not exactly sure but if you ever want to launch an app without all the  other text you can use `alt + f2`

Comment: @TrailRider That is not correct. An `&` at the end of a command makes it run as a background [job](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_77.html). `&` and `&&` are *different operators*. Furthermore, `command1 && command2` *will not always run `command2`*. The right hand side of an `&&` expression only runs if the left hand side of the expression terminated indicating success.